# table or view-fast load access mode is giving error --- Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0202040 Error at CONTAINER [OLE DB Destination

Tags: ssis, data-conversion, oledbdestination

I am mirroring the tables from Sql server to Oracle. So its working absolutely find when I choose sql command as Data access mode. But I have millions of records in my table so wanted to switch Table or view -fast load access mode. As soon as I select fast load as data access mode it is showing me this error. Not able to click on mapping option. Can somebody please advise here`[![enter code here][1]][1]`

### below is the error details
TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0202040
Error at SMO_CONTAINER [OLE DB Destination [266]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "OraOLEDB"  Hresult: 0x80040E21  Description: "The system cannot find message text for message number 0x80040e21 in the message file for OraOLEDB.".

Error at SMO_CONTAINER [OLE DB Destination [266]]: Failed to open a fastload rowset for ""CTSO"."CAP_CLS_CT_CONTAINER"". Check that the object exists in the database.

Answer (score 0):

attaching the DFD details.[image]
This the PKG I have made.trying to do the data conversion and dump the the tables from sql server to oracle.